# ADAL requireADLogin and angular-ui-router?

Tags: angularjs, adal, adal.js

I have an angular (1.x) SPA, and am trying to protect it via ADAL to require auth through an Azure AD.
However, even the routes/pages/states marked with `requireADLogin: true` seem to let the user access them without requiring auth.

I wonder if the problem is I'm using [angular-ui-router](https://ui-router.github.io/) (0.4.2) instead of ngRoute, and therefore my configuration of the routes/states is not really taken into account.

My HTMl template is displaying `userInfo` and on first load that's `{"isAuthenticated":false,"userName":"","loginError":""}`, but the page loads (including the child route/state), even if I set `requireADLogin: true` on the shell and/or child state (see below).

I have a login button leading to the login sequence in a pop-up, and when that completes, the page shows the userInfo for the logged in user,
so I think I got the rest lined up.
    v

```
// My top-level app config block:
function AppConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider, adalAuthenticationServiceProvider) {

    // Configure the urlRouteProvider to redirect to /intro by default
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/intro");

    // Configure the ADAL Auth Provider
    adalAuthenticationServiceProvider.init({
        tenant: "[MyTenantID]",
        clientId: "[MyClientID]",
        popUp: true
    }
    // // pass http provider to inject request interceptor to attach tokens
    // $httpProvider
    );
}

// Later I set up my shell state/route (all other states are children of this one):
$stateProvider.state('shell', {
    //blank url as the shell is an abstract parent to every other state
    url: '',
    templateUrl: 'app/shell/shell.html',
    controller: 'ShellController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    abstract: true,
    requireADLogin: false   // <-- tried with requireADLogin: true
});

// Intro (aka shell.intro) should be the default state:
$stateProvider.state('shell.intro', {
    url: '/intro',
    templateUrl: 'app/intro/intro.html',
    controller: 'IntroController',
    controllerAs: 'vm',
    data: {
        pageTitle: 'Intro'
    },
    requireADLogin: true
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a quick test with your code snippet, and find the main criminal could be the operation of commenting the sentence `$httpProvider` under `adalAuthenticationServiceProvider.init` function.

Please uncomment this sentence and the reason is also provided in the code sample at https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js#getting-started:

> `$httpProvider   // pass http provider to inject request interceptor to attach tokens`

It will fix your issue on my side, please try it.

Comment: Out sick - will try asap and update. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Uncommenting the $httpProvider line seems to have done the trick - thank you!